# Can Socket.SendAsync send null("") stream?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

First of all, sorry to my poor English ability ...

My server's disconnect detection method is following code.

```
string receiveMessage = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receiveBuffer, 0, length);

   if (receiveMessage == "") 
       return false; // disconnect
```

I'm really inconvenient with this. >:^{

My Question is,

1. When I send message like ""(blank), this can be sended?
2. How can I more develop this code?

Comment: The question somehow does not fit in with the code snippet. Regarding the code, I'd suggest to inspect the `length` before converting the payload to string.

Comment: TCP is an *endless stream of bytes*, not *messages*. If you want to do messages, it's up to you to implement *message framing* atop TCP or usually a better option is to pick a higher level protocol that already does message framing.

Comment: If you want to model a graceful shutdown, I'd suggest you create a specialized message for that in your protocol.

Comment: I'm worrying about 'client's accidentely closing'.
In this case, Client can't send any closing message. And Server will can't release socket to pool.

That is my worry.

Comment: @JaeEun eventually the socket will timeout though, and then you'll read 0 bytes.

Comment: ^^ this. You can also try to send "ping" (not ICMP) if the line is idle for X amount of time. If the connection has been closed unilaterally, you should get an exception, then.